# if...else..for in list_comprehensions not working

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, list-comprehension

I'm trying to make this work but apparently there's some syntax error and I'm struggling to understand what is wrong with it. The part that is not working is the else condition. If I remove it, the first part works as it's supposed to. What I'm trying to do is check if the type of the element (y['type]) is either environmental or shock and based on that return different key:value pairs

```
mylist=[{'matrice':x['matrice'],'n':x['n'],'id':x['id'],'status':x['status'],
'events':[{'date':y['timestamp'],'type':y['type'],'extradata':{'temp': y['temperature']}} 
for y in db.get_data(x['id']) if y['type']=='environmental' 
else {'date':y['timestamp'],'type':y['type'],'extra':{'Intensity_X': y['x_axis']}}]}
for x in older_stuff]
```

Comment: I recommend breaking that code up into multiple lines. it's very difficult to read when you have to scroll so far horizontally

Comment: Ok, thank you! Will do it ASAP!

Comment: is there a reason this has to be a list comprehension?

Comment: I find it quite exciting to use and easier to work with honestly.

Comment: this is very difficult to read as far as python code goes. this is easier than writing out normal for loops and functions? at the very least, I would break the if/else logic out into a function. get that working with an normal `for` loop first, then convert to a list comprehension.

Comment: If there is a syntax error you can probably find it by indenting each expression so it's easier to read and understand the flow of your list comprehension. But this is better suited to a proper loop anyways since there are so many properties to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place your if/else before your first for loop like that:

```
mylist = [{'matrice': x['matrice'], 'n': x['n'], 'id': x['id'], 'status': x['status'],
           'events': [{'date': y['timestamp'], 'type': y['type'], 'extradata': {'temp': y['temperature']}}
                      if y['type'] == 'environmental'
                      else {'date': y['timestamp'], 'type': y['type'], 'extra': {'Intensity_X': y['x_axis']}}]}
          for y in db.get_data(x['id'])
          for x in older_stuff]
```

Still. as already pointed out in the comments, in this case it would be much more readable to use multiple statements.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked and I followed the suggestions given before to me and it's now working as it should!

Comment: You're welcome, nice to hear that it works now! :)